# How to copy node value in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Here is my xml file, where I need to check the value of SOME_SW_INSTALLED, if it is IS_TRUE then the value of SOME_HW_INSTALLED should be IS_TRUE(vice-versa). I am new and do not have any knowledge of xslt.

```
<MEDIA_FAMILY>
      <SOME_ID ReadOnly="true">1</SOME_ID>
      <SOME_NAME ReadOnly="true">somecode</SOME_NAME>
      <SOME_DESCRIPTION ReadOnly="true">something</SOME_DESCRIPTION>
      <SOME_SW_INSTALLED ReadOnly="true">IS_TRUE</SOME_SW_INSTALLED>
      <SOME_HW_INSTALLED ReadOnly="false">IS_FALSE</SOME_HW_INSTALLED>
</MEDIA_FAMILY>
```

Here is my xslt but some one can suggest me simpler way

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()|comment()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()|comment()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/MEDIA_FAMILY/SOME_HW_INSTALLED">
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test= "../SOME_SW_INSTALLED = 'IS_TRUE'">
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
           <xsl:text>IS_TRUE</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
          
       </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
           <xsl:text>IS_FALSE</xsl:text>
        </xsl:copy>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: I have script but I need simpler way by just checking value-of variable

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to foresee all the possible situations and their expected outcome from a single example. Would this work for you?

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SOME_HW_INSTALLED">
     <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="../SOME_SW_INSTALLED"/>
    </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```